# Table Column length is 100 but View Column length is 150 in SQL Developer

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am using SQL Developer 19.1.0. and Oracle Database 12c Standard Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production.

I have created a View on a Table. In SQL Developer, when I double click the Table it is showing the `DATA_TYPE` as `NVARCHAR2(100 CHAR)` for a column but when I double click the VIEW it is showing the `DATA_TYPE` as `NVARCHAR2(150 CHAR)`.

Similarly, all the `NVARCHAR2` columns length in the VIEW is showing 1.5 times that of Table column's length.

What is the reason and how do I fix it?

Edit - Added he following DB Parameters

```
NLS_RDBMS_VERSION           12.1.0.2.0
NLS_NCHAR_CONV_EXCP         FALSE
NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS        BYTE
NLS_COMP                    BINARY
NLS_DUAL_CURRENCY           $
NLS_TIMESTAMP_TZ_FORMAT     DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SSXFF AM TZR
NLS_TIME_TZ_FORMAT          HH.MI.SSXFF AM TZR
NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT        DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SSXFF AM
NLS_TIME_FORMAT             HH.MI.SSXFF AM
NLS_SORT                    BINARY
NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE           AMERICAN
NLS_DATE_FORMAT             DD-MON-RR
NLS_CALENDAR                GREGORIAN
NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS      .,
NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET      UTF8
NLS_CHARACTERSET            AL32UTF8
NLS_ISO_CURRENCY            AMERICA
NLS_CURRENCY                $
NLS_TERRITORY               AMERICA
NLS_LANGUAGE                AMERICAN
```

When I user DESCRIBE command to view TABLE and VIEW I get NVARCHAR2(150)

Comment: Please include the `CREATE VIEW` statement you used to create the view.

Comment: I'm not seeing that, in SQL Developer 19.2. With a very basic view (`create view ... as select * from ....`), the table shows `NVARCHAR2(100 CHAR)`, the view shows `NVARCHAR2(100)` with the 'char'. Possibly an earlier (or later!) version is incorrectly adjusting the number shown, as a display issue rather than something that affects actual data. Which version are you on, and what are your database and national character sets? What do you see if you `describe` the table and view from a worksheet, or in SQL\*Plus?

Comment: [Possibly related?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/125862/847)

Comment: When I use the DESC command, I get NVARCHAR2(150) for both TABLE and VIEW. NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET = UTF8
NLS_CHARACTERSET = AL32UTF8

Comment: Added more details in the question